# Detach database failed for Server 'MONO-PC\SQLEXPRESS'

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Error : **"Detach database failed for Server 'MONO-PC\SQLEXPRESS'."**

```
Public Sub bk()
        Try
            Dim strDatabasePath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC.mdf")
            Dim strdbLogPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CombinePath(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "LIC_log.ldf")
            ' DB.Connection can be any valid SQLConnection which you might already be using in your application
            Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString)
            Dim srvCon As New ServerConnection(con)
            Dim srv As Server = New Server(srvCon)
            If srv.Databases.Contains(strDatabasePath) Then
                If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    con.Close()
                End If
                srv.DetachDatabase(strDatabasePath, True)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strDatabasePath, "c:\backup\LIC.mdf", True)
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strdbLogPath, "c:\backup\LIC_log.ldf", True)
                MessageBox.Show("Backup taken successfully")
            End If
            srvCon.Disconnect()
            con.Open()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Why does it fail??Any Help Appreciated.

Comment: Can you at least post the error/exception you're getting?

Comment: "Detach database failed for Server 'MONO-PC\SQLEXPRESS'."  This is what i get when it executes this line `srv.DetachDatabase(strDatabasePath, True)`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the path for the database name and you should extract the file names from the database object. Here is a rewrite that will work for any database:

```
Public Sub bk()
    Try
        Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(LIC.My.Settings.LICConnectionString)
            Dim sDatabaseName As String

            con.Open()

            sDatabaseName = con.Database

            con.Close()

            Dim srvCon As New ServerConnection(con)
            Dim srv As Server = New Server(srvCon)

            If srv.Databases.Contains(sDatabaseName) Then
                Dim oDatabase As Database
                Dim cFiles As New List(Of String)

                ' Get a local reference to the database
                oDatabase = srv.Databases(sDatabaseName)

                ' Collect the list of database files associated with this database
                For Each oFileGroup As FileGroup In oDatabase.FileGroups
                    For Each oFile As DataFile In oFileGroup.Files
                        cFiles.Add(oFile.FileName)
                    Next
                Next

                ' And collect the list of log files associated with this database
                For Each oFile As LogFile In oDatabase.LogFiles
                    cFiles.Add(oFile.FileName)
                Next

                ' Ensure nothing is using the database
                srv.KillAllProcesses(sDatabaseName)

                ' Detach the database
                srv.DetachDatabase(sDatabaseName, False)

                ' And finally, copy all of the files identified above to the backup directory
                For Each sFileName As String In cFiles
                    System.IO.File.Copy(sFileName, System.IO.Path.Combine("c:\backup\", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFileName)), True)
                Next

                MessageBox.Show("Backup taken successfully")
            End If
            srvCon.Disconnect()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```